# Resolve long initial load time in large ReactJS application using a service worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, service-worker

I have spent many hours trying to resolve this issue and I am at a loss for what to try next. My React application takes **6+ seconds** on the initial load which is not great as a first impression.

I have structured my application well, am using `lazy()` on pages and some of the larger components and code splitting is working as intended. However, on the first `(ServiceWorker)` request there is a huge delay of ~5 seconds.

[image]

What is going on here? How can I further debug this request?

Comment: Unfortunately this is just too broad of a question to answer. We don't have access to your source code, and there are hundreds of reasons why you have a long initial render time. For instance, have you tried to do any SSR?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [source-map-explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer) to display all packages size in your bundle files